# Formula for the floor of $n/2$, to be proved by induction

Tags: arithmetic, induction, divisibility

[image]

How do you compute this when the base case is all wrong?

Comment: whats floor of 0?

Comment: What's wrong with the base case? Floor of $0$ is $0$.

Comment: "Impossible" is a strong claim - it means the problem cannot be solved, not that you are having trouble. It is not a subjective word. Mathematicians often can prove something is impossible, so it is a bad idea to use it as an exaggeration.

Comment: You probably want to have two bases cases: $n=0$ and $n=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Use $$\left\lfloor\frac{m+2}2\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac m2+1\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac m2\right\rfloor+1$$

In fact, $$\left\lfloor\frac mn+I\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac mn\right\rfloor+I$$ for any integers $I,m,n$